# Split a query result based on the result count

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have a query based on basic criteria that will return X number of records on any given day.

I'm trying to check the result of the basic query then apply a percentage split to it based on the total of X and split it in 2 buckets. Each bucket will be a percentage of the total query result returned in X.

For example:

- Query A returns 3500 records.
- If the number of records returned from Query A is <= 3000, then split the 3500 records  into a 40% / 60% split (1,400 / 2,100).
- If the number of records returned from Query A is >=3001 and <=50,000 then split the records into a 10% / 90% split.Etc. Etc.
- I want the actual records returned, and not just the math acting on the records that returns one row with a number in it (in the column).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how you want to display different parts of the resulting set of rows, so I've just added additional column(`part`) in the resulting set of rows that contains values `1` indicating that row belongs to the first part and `2` - second part.

```
select z.*
     , case 
         when  cnt_all <= 3000 and cnt <= 40 
         then 1
         when  (cnt_all between 3001 and 50000) and (cnt <= 10) 
         then 1  
         else 2
       end part
  from (select t.*
             , 100*(count(col1) over(order by col1) / count(col1) over() )cnt 
             , count(col1) over() cnt_all
         from split_rowset t
         order by col1
        ) z
```

[Demo #1](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f881/1)  number of rows 3000.
[Demo #2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/31c59/1) number of rows 3500.

For better usability you can create a view using the query above and then query that view filtering by `part` column.

[Demo #3](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d23ea/8) using of a view.